# How to clear form fields once and not every time a focus event triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me nuts - I know what needs to happen and I thought the scripts would work but I can't see where it's going wrong.

I've got a form that calculates a mix of products based on different inputs.

First, someone can click a radio button with a fixed amount and the form figures out the amounts based on a fixed percentage that has been determined by out product sales team.  In this case, clicking on the radio buttons, resets the form and deletes any previous amount entered into the 'Other' field.

Second, if the fixed amounts aren't enough, you can enter in an amount and use the same percentage mix. This is the 'Other' field and it clears the radio buttons and the amounts in the fields.

Lastly, and the part that is causing problems, if neither fixed option is wanted, they you can enter the amounts desired in the fields and the form will keep the totals and change the percentages to suit.  This also clears the radio buttons and the amount from the 'Custom' field whenever focus is placed on any one of the text fields.

However, as I move from field to field to enter amounts, the form keeps resetting itself every time I focus on the next field. I've tried to add a condition so that if no radio button is selected and the custom field is not empty, the fields are cleared.  The intent is that on subsequent fields, the condition changes so that the custom field is empty and the form stops clearing the fields.

But, it's not working like that - every field that receives the focus clears the fields and I'm not having any luck figuring out how to fix it.

Sorry in advance if this is long - I'm sure the jquery could be cleaned up but this is what I have for right now.

Many thanks in advance for any and all help.

Fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/saabStory/cbtL0gm6/1/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif}
        .ckCustomTable {border:none;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#fff;font-size:10pt;width:800px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th, .ckCustomTable tr td{padding:4px 2px;border:1px solid #ddd;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#fff !important;text-align:center;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(1),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(1) {width:60px !important;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(2),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(2) {width:75px !important;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(3),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(3) {width:75px !important;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(4),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(4) {width:75px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(5),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(5) {width:75px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(6),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(6) {width:75px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(7),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(7) {width:60px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(8),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(8) {width:90px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(9),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(9){}
        .ckCustomTable tr th:nth-child(10),.ckCustomTable tr td:nth-child(10){background-color:#0f0 !important;}

        .ckCustomTable tr td #tmCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #smCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #tgCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #trCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #ddCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #lmCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #ttCustom,
        .ckCustomTable tr td #soCustom {text-align:center;border:1px solid #0ff;font-size:9pt;color:#666;width:35px;}
        .ckCustomTable tr td #mxCustomTotal {text-align:center;padding:2px 1px;border:1px solid #ddd;font-size:9pt;color:#666;width:35px;}

        .ckSelectGrid {border:none;border-collapse:collapse;width:800px;margin-bottom:10px;}
        .ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(1),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(3),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(5),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(7),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(9) {width:50px;padding:0;text-align:right !important;border:none;border-collapse:collapse;}
        .ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(2),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(4),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(6),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(8),.ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(10) {width:100px;text-align:left;border:none;border-collapse:collapse;padding-left:0;}
        .ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(9) {width:80px !important;}
        .ckSelectGrid tr td:nth-child(10) {width:90px !important;padding:0;margin:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="ckSelectGrid" id="selectAmt">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="cookieSelect" id="count100" class="" value="100"></td>
            <td class="paddingLeft10"><label class="font105" for="count100">100</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="cookieSelect" id="count250" class="" value="250"></td>
            <td><label class="font105" for="count250">250</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="cookieSelect" id="count300" class="" value="300"></td>
            <td><label class="font105" for="count300">300</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="cookieSelect" id="count600" class="" value="600"></td>
            <td><label class="font105" for="count600">600</label></td>
            <td><label class="font105 paddingRight10"  for="cookieGoal">Other</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="countOther" name="countOther" class="form_Field60 key-numeric" style="font-size:9pt !important;" tabindex="1" autocomplete="nope" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="ckCustomTable">
        <tr>
            <th>ITEM</th>
            <th>TM</th>
            <th>SM</th>
            <th>TG</th>
            <th>TR</th>
            <th>DD</th>
            <th>LM</th>
            <th>TT</th>
            <th>SO</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mix %</td>
            <td id="tmPercent">27%</td>
            <td id="smPercent">23%</td>
            <td id="tgPercent">15%</td>
            <td id="trPercent">9%</td>
            <td id="ddPercent">8%</td>
            <td id="lmPercent">9%</td>
            <td id="ttPercent">2%</td>
            <td id="soPercent">7%</td>
            <td id="mxPercent">100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >AMT:</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="tmTotal" id="tmTotal" tabindex="10" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="smTotal" id="smTotal" tabindex="11" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="tgTotal" id="tgTotal" tabindex="12" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="trTotal" id="trTotal" tabindex="13" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="ddTotal" id="ddTotal" tabindex="14" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="lmTotal" id="lmTotal" tabindex="15" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="ttTotal" id="ttTotal" tabindex="16" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="soTotal" id="soTotal" tabindex="17" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;" class="key-numeric textCenter" name="mxTotal" id="mxTotal" readonly tabindex="-1" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" name="countOtherTemp" id="countOtherTemp" placeholder="Count Other Temp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="tmTotalTemp" id="tmTotalTemp" placeholder="TMTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="smTotalTemp" id="smTotalTemp" placeholder="SMTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="tgTotalTemp" id="tgTotalTemp" placeholder="TGTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="trTotalTemp" id="trTotalTemp" placeholder="TRTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="ddTotalTemp" id="ddTotalTemp" placeholder="DDTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="lmTotalTemp" id="lmTotalTemp" placeholder="LMTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="ttTotalTemp" id="ttTotalTemp" placeholder="TTTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="soTotalTemp" id="soTotalTemp" placeholder="SOTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="mxTotalTemp" id="mxTotalTemp" placeholder="MXTemp" tabindex="-1" value="">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>                                                                                                   <!-- V 1.11.2 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>                                                                                                 <!-- V 1.11.2 -->
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $('.key-numeric').keypress(function(e) {
            var verified = (e.which == 8 || e.which == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^0-9]/);
            if (verified) {e.preventDefault();}
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
    //= CUSTOM MIX CALCULATIONS ====================================================================================================================================
        // INITIALIZE STANDARD COOKIE MIX VARS =====================================================================================================================
            var tmTotalTemp = null;
            var smTotalTemp = null;
            var tgTotalTemp = null;
            var trTotalTemp = null;
            var ddTotalTemp = null;
            var lmTotalTemp = null;
            var ttTotalTemp = null;
            var soTotalTemp = null;
            var mxTotalTemp = null;
            var countOtherTemp = null;
        //= RADIO BUTTON SELECTION =================================================================================================================================
            $("#selectAmt :radio").change(function() {
                $("#countOther,#countOtherTemp").val('');
                $("#tmPercent").html("27%");
                $("#smPercent").html("23%");
                $("#tgPercent").html("15%");
                $("#trPercent").html("9%");
                $("#ddPercent").html("8%");
                $("#lmPercent").html("9%");
                $("#ttPercent").html("2%");
                $("#soPercent").html("7%");
                $("#mxPercent").html("100%");
                tmTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.27);
                smTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.23);
                tgTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.15);
                trTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.09);
                ddTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.08);
                lmTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.09);
                ttTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.02);
                soTotalTemp = parseInt(Math.round(this.value)*.07);
                mxTotalTemp = Math.round(tmTotalTemp + smTotalTemp + tgTotalTemp + trTotalTemp + ddTotalTemp + lmTotalTemp + ttTotalTemp + soTotalTemp);
                $("#tmTotal").val(tmTotalTemp);
                $("#smTotal").val(smTotalTemp);
                $("#tgTotal").val(tgTotalTemp);
                $("#trTotal").val(trTotalTemp);
                $("#ddTotal").val(ddTotalTemp);
                $("#lmTotal").val(lmTotalTemp);
                $("#ttTotal").val(ttTotalTemp);
                $("#soTotal").val(soTotalTemp);
                $("#mxTotal").val(mxTotalTemp);
                $("#countOther").val(countOtherTemp);
                $("#tmTotalTemp").val(tmTotalTemp);
                $("#smTotalTemp").val(smTotalTemp);
                $("#tgTotalTemp").val(tgTotalTemp);
                $("#trTotalTemp").val(trTotalTemp);
                $("#ddTotalTemp").val(ddTotalTemp);
                $("#lmTotalTemp").val(lmTotalTemp);
                $("#ttTotalTemp").val(ttTotalTemp);
                $("#soTotalTemp").val(soTotalTemp);
                $("#mxTotalTemp").val(mxTotalTemp);
            });
        //= OTHER AMOUNT CALCULATION ===============================================================================================================================
            $('#countOther').on("input",function(){
                $("#countOtherTemp").val($('#countOther').val());
                $("#tmPercent").html("27%");
                $("#smPercent").html("23%");
                $("#tgPercent").html("15%");
                $("#trPercent").html("9%");
                $("#ddPercent").html("8%");
                $("#lmPercent").html("9%");
                $("#ttPercent").html("2%");
                $("#soPercent").html("7%");
                $("#mxPercent").html("100%");
                $("#count100,#count250,#count300,#count600").attr('checked', false);
                $("#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal,#mxTotal").val('');
                $("#tmTotalTemp,#smTotalTemp,#tgTotalTemp,#trTotalTemp,#ddTotalTemp,#lmTotalTemp,#ttTotalTemp,#soTotalTemp,#mxTotalTemp").val('');
                $("#tmTotal,#tmTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.27));
                $("#smTotal,#smTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.23));
                $("#tgTotal,#tgTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.15));
                $("#trTotal,#trTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.09));
                $("#ddTotal,#ddTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.08));
                $("#lmTotal,#lmTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.09));
                $("#ttTotal,#ttTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.02));
                $("#soTotal,#soTotalTemp").val(Math.round($('#countOther').val()*.07));
                $("#mxTotal,#mxTotalTemp").val(Number($("#tmTotal").val()) + Number($("#smTotal").val()) + Number($("#tgTotal").val()) + Number($("#trTotal").val()) + Number($("#ddTotal").val()) + Number($("#lmTotal").val()) + Number($("#ttTotal").val()) + Number($("#soTotal").val()) + Number($("#mxTotal").val()));
            });

    //= CUSTOM COOKIE MIX CALCULATIONS =============================================================================================================================
        // INITIALIZE CUSTOM COOKIE MIX VARS =======================================================================================================================
            $('#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal').focus(function() {
                $("#amountOther").val('');
                var radioCheck = $('input:radio[name=cookieSelect]:checked').val();
                if (radioCheck || ($("#amountOther").val() !== '')) {
                    $("#count100,#count250,#count300,#count600").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal,#mxTotal,#countOther").val('');
                    // return false;
                }
            });
            $("#tmTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#smTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#tgTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#trTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#ddTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#lmTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#ttTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            $("#soTotal").each(function(){                                                   //= CALCULATE SUM FOR PRODUCTS ===================================================
                $(this).on("input",function(){
                    calculateOrderSum();
                });
            });
            function calculateOrderSum() {
                var tm = Number($('#tmTotal').val());
                var sm = Number($('#smTotal').val());
                var tg = Number($('#tgTotal').val());
                var tr = Number($('#trTotal').val());
                var dd = Number($('#ddTotal').val());
                var lm = Number($('#lmTotal').val());
                var tt = Number($('#ttTotal').val());
                var so = Number($('#soTotal').val());
                var mx = tm + sm + tg + tr + dd + lm + tt + so
                $("#mxTotal").val(mx);
//= POPULATE TEMP FIELDS ===========================================================================================================================================
                $("#tmTotalTemp").val(tm);
                $("#smTotalTemp").val(sm);
                $("#tgTotalTemp").val(tg);
                $("#trTotalTemp").val(tr);
                $("#ddTotalTemp").val(dd);
                $("#lmTotalTemp").val(lm);
                $("#ttTotalTemp").val(tt);
                $("#soTotalTemp").val(so);
                $("#mxTotalTemp").val(mx);

//= CALCULATE PERCENTAGES ==========================================================================================================================================
                var tmPercent = Math.round((($("#tmTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var smPercent = Math.round((($("#smTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var tgPercent = Math.round((($("#tgTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var trPercent = Math.round((($("#trTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var ddPercent = Math.round((($("#ddTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var lmPercent = Math.round((($("#lmTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var ttPercent = Math.round((($("#ttTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var soPercent = Math.round((($("#soTotal").val()) / ($("#mxTotal").val())) * 100);
                var mxPercent = (tmPercent + smPercent + tgPercent + trPercent + ddPercent + lmPercent + ttPercent + soPercent);
                $("#tmPercent").html(tmPercent + "%");
                $("#smPercent").html(smPercent + "%");
                $("#tgPercent").html(tgPercent + "%");
                $("#trPercent").html(trPercent + "%");
                $("#ddPercent").html(ddPercent + "%");
                $("#lmPercent").html(lmPercent + "%");
                $("#ttPercent").html(ttPercent + "%");
                $("#soPercent").html(soPercent + "%");
                $("#mxPercent").html(mxPercent + "%");
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: comment this line no 91 $("#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal,#mxTotal,#countOther").val('');

Comment: on every next focus you are setting these ids back to empty values

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple mistake, but it looks like this might be it:

Simply change every instance of `#amountOther` to `#countOther`.

Specifically in here:

```
$('#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal').focus(function() {
    $("#amountOther").val('');
    var radioCheck = $('input:radio[name=cookieSelect]:checked').val();
    if (radioCheck || ($("#amountOther").val() !== '')) {
      $("#count100,#count250,#count300,#count600").prop("checked", false);
      $("#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal,#mxTotal,#countOther").val('');
    // return false;
    }
  });
```

Change to this:

```
$('#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal').focus(function() {
    //**This line below**
    $("#countOther").val('');
    var radioCheck = $('input:radio[name=cookieSelect]:checked').val();
    //**Also the line below here**
    if (radioCheck || ($("#countOther").val() !== '')) {
      $("#count100,#count250,#count300,#count600").prop("checked", false);
      $("#tmTotal,#smTotal,#tgTotal,#trTotal,#ddTotal,#lmTotal,#ttTotal,#soTotal,#mxTotal,#countOther").val('');
    // return false;
    }
  });
```